# Cadlag modification of a ladcag process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, skorohod-space

Recently, I have been studying stochastic processes and came across an interesting question about cadlag modifications of processes and I couldn't find the answer on the internet. My question is written below.

Suppose that we have the probability space $(D[\mathbb{R}^+, S]), \mathcal{B}_S, \mathbb{P}) $ and the canonical process $ X_t(\omega) = \omega(t) $. Here, $D[\mathbb{R}^+, S] $ denotes the set of all left continuous with right limits functions (ladcag paths) defined on $\mathbb{R}^+ = [0,+\infty)$, with values in a finite set $S$. We equip $D[\mathbb{R}^+, S])$ with the usual cylinder $\sigma$-algebra. My question is, do we have a cadlag modification $Y_t$ of $X_t$? That is, is there a process $Y_t$, defined on the same probability space such that

$$ \forall t \geq 0, \mathbb{P}(Y_t = X_t) = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{P}(Y = (Y_t)_{t\geq 0} \ \text{has a cadlag path}) = 1? $$

My first thought was to define for each $\omega$

$$Y_t(\omega):= \begin{cases} \omega(t), \quad \text{if} \quad t \in C_\omega, \\ 
\lim_{s \rightarrow t^+}\omega(s), \quad \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}  $$
where $C_\omega := \{t \geq 0, \omega \ \text{is continuous at t} \}$. In otherwords, I modified the "left jump points" of any ladcag process to "right jump points" so that its path becomes cadlag. But this scheme had me stuck at proving
$$ 1 = \mathbb{P}(Y_t = X_t) = \mathbb{P}(\omega: Y_t(\omega) = \omega(t)) = \mathbb{P}(\omega: \omega \ \text{is continuous at t}),  \quad \forall t \geq 0. $$

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: The answer is no: If you define the modification $Y_t$ of $X_t$ as you do then the requirement $\forall t\ge 0$, $\mathbb P(Y_t=X_t)=1$ is equivalent to "$X$ is $\mathbb P$-a.s. continuous".

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought: the measure of the set of continuous paths (hence, constant paths) $\mathbb{P}( \text{all continuous paths})$ can be anything. Therefore, my definition of $Y_t$ is not a good way to have the desired modification. It seems there is no cadlad modification to me but I can't prove this.

Answer (score 1):

A làdcàg process does not always admit a càdlàg modification. Consider the case where the process $Y$ has a jump at a specific time $t$ with probability greater than $0$. Concretely, consider the example $$Y(t):=\mathbb 1\bigg\{0\leq t\leq \frac12\bigg\}$$
[image]

The most natural "càdlàg modification" one can imagine is the function $$X(t):=\mathbb 1\bigg\{0\leq t<\frac12\bigg\}$$ [image]

Indeed, it is the only càdlàg process $X$ such that $X(t)$ has the same distribution as $Y(t)$ for all $t\neq 1/2$ and by right-continuity of a càdlàg function we see that $X(1/2)=0$ is the only choice we can make.

However, clearly $X(1/2)=0$ and $Y(1/2)=1$ do not have the same distribution.

As the example shows, jumps occuring at a fixed time $t$ with positive probability can rule out càdlàg modifications. However, assuming the process $Y$ is [stochastically continuous](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Stochastic_continuity), there are a few Theorems giving extra conditions showing that such a process $Y$ does admit a càdlàg modification. In [this StackExchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493511/stochastically-continuous-implies-existence-c%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g-modiciation) such a Theorem is given, perhaps under a somewhat ugly extra condition. [This almost-sure-math blog](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/18/cadlag-modifications/) discusses the existence of càdlàg modifications for semi-martingales.